# PS4 Pro not connecting to dualshock 4 despite controllers working in safe mode

Tags: ps4, controllers

my PS4 Pro is not connecting to both my dualshocks. At first it started by not being able to turn on the console by just pressing the PS button, now I have to manually switch it "on" on the console itself. But when PS4 is in safe mode both my controllers(with usb cable) work and very responsive. I also rebuilt its database, reset the connection of both controllers and pair by PS button and share button. I also paired it before to my PC (bluetooth), both worked just fine. I feel the problem here is the console itself.